# Тире в неполном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

"Одна хорошо, а две лучше". Нужно ли ставить тире?

Answer (score 1):

В неполном предложении на месте пропуска члена предложения при наличии интонационной паузы ставится тире. В предложениях простой конструкции, как в в Вашем случае, тире может не ставиться. Так что и один, и другой вариант для Вашего предложения подходит. Если хотите интонационно выделить слово "лучше", следует поставить тире.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы добавить слово "голова", например, то пауза (и тире) станет как-то более желательной:

> Одна голова хорошо, а две - лучше.

Может потому, что во второй части ощущается пропуск этой самой "головы"?