# Тире в неполном предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация

"Береги платье снову, а честь смолоду". В этой пословице тире нужно после слова "честь", ведь можно восстановить глагол "береги" из первой части? Что меня смутило, так это то, что в интернете в одном источнике было написано с тире, а в другом - без него.

Comment: См. также: Тире в неполном предложении (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/%d0%a2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта корректны.

В предложениях такого типа тире ставится, если в месте пропуска делается пауза: *Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо (Т.);*

Заметим, что при таком толковании союза А в значении несоответствия значение сопоставления можно не рассматривать как отдельное: значение А возникающее в контекстах типа Береги платье снову, **а честь — смолоду**, можно представить как такой частный случай значения А2, когда следствие, вытекающее из соположения двух фактов (или, как в данном случае, двух рекомендаций) можно выразить так: ‘и в этом отношении они — платье и честь —сходны ’. [Е. В. Падучева. Эгоцентрическая семантика союзов А и НО (1997)] (Еле́на Ви́кторовна [Па́дучева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0,_%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) (род. 26 сентября 1935 года, Москва) — российский лингвист, один из крупнейших специалистов по русской и общей семантике)

При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится: *Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку (Ч.); Из нашей батареи только Солёный пойдёт на барже, мы же со строевой частью (Ч.); Алёша смотрел на них, а они на него (Дост.); У вора один грех, а у нас с хозяином десять (Остр.); …Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие (Леон.).*
 [(§ 6. Тире в неполном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93,3#pp93), п. 5)

Нужно добавить, что классический вариант этой пословицы не содержит тире:

Служи верно, кому присягнешь; слушайся начальников; за их лаской не гоняйся; на службу не напрашивайся; от службы не отговаривайся; и помни пословицу: береги платье снову, **а честь смолоду**». [А. С. Пушкин. Капитанская дочка (1836)]

Береги платье снову, **а честь смолоду**.([В.И. Даль. Пословицы русского народа](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/32483/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8))